# MS Access 2007: How to summarize two rows by date and customer

Tags: ms-access

Data:

```
Customer | Ship_Date | Ship_Weight

Peter      08/01/14    120  
Peter      08/01/14    285
```

How do I summarize these two rows to get an answer by date:

```
Customer | Ship Date | Ship Weight
Peter      08/01/14    405
```

As you can see, there are multiple shipments on a single day.  I want to summarize it to show unique ship dates with total ship weight.

I am using MS Access 2007.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Customer, Ship_Date, Sum(Ship_Weight) as Sum_Weight
From tblMyTable
Group By Customer, Ship_Date
```

You're going to need to make sure your Ship_Date is in Date format only and not DateTime, otherwise it will group by both Date and Time.  If necessary, you may need to format that within the query.